# Batch to read partial xml file

Tags: shell, scripting, batch-file, command

I'm trying to make a batch file to pull data out of a file and set it as a variable.

The tricky part is I need to read a XML file, and I only need the data between the quotes of the following line...

```
narrative="I only need this text here"
```

The text in that line can also contain spaces, brackets, slashes, dashes and colons.

**SAMPLE XML FILE** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
    <cadcall>
        <call callnumber="123456" jurisdiction="abcd" department="dept 1" complaint="cost" priority="M" calltencode="" callername="Persons Name" phonenumber="Cell Number HERE" narrative="[10/02/2012 14:56:27 : pos9 : PERSON] Fairly long narrative here describing issue of dispatch, but sometimes these can be short." alarmtype="" ocanumber="0000000000" disposition1="TRAN" />
    </cadcall>
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper tool to do this is `xmllint` from `libxml`, please, provide a more complete XML example, I will tell you how to use a `Xpath` request on your `XML`.

**EDIT** :

here a solution using Xpath (with a little hack : `contains`) :

```
xmllint --xpath '/cadcall/call/@narrative[contains(.,'.')]' file.xml
```

Comment: Here is a complete example.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <cadcall>
  <call callnumber="123456" jurisdiction="abcd" department="dept 1" complaint="cost" priority="M" calltencode="" callername="Persons Name" phonenumber="Cell Number HERE" narrative="[10/02/2012 14:56:27 : pos9 : PERSON] Fairly long narrative here describing issue of dispatch, but sometimes these can be short." alarmtype="" ocanumber="0000000000" disposition1="TRAN" />

Comment: When I run this, I get an XPath Error : Invalid expression.   It shows a carret pointing to the period in; (x,'.')]'

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the complete input, just based on your example line. grep works for you.

```
kent$  echo 'narrative="I only need this text here"'|grep -Po '(?<=narrative=")[^"]*'
I only need this text here
```